# Cakephp: Invalid key for encrypt(), key must be at least 256 bits (32 bytes) long while setting the cookies

Tags: cakephp, cookies, cakephp-3.0

I am enabling cookies on my cakephp app as mentioned in the documentation problem is i am getting the security error while setting the cookies.

> Invalid key for encrypt(), key must be at least 256 bits (32 bytes) long.

I have searched but did not find a solution for this error.

In my controller i am setting and `array` to the cookie's `$key`.

```
$this->Auth->setUser($contactData);
$this->Cookie->write('contactData', $contactData);
```

I have also enabled the component in `appController.php`.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Either you have configured an invalid encryption key for the cookie component (see the `key` option), or your application's salt is either invalid, or not being set at all (check your `config/app.php` and `config/bootstrap.php` for the `Security.salt` option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your Security salt in app.php does not have the correct length. Adjust it to match what the error message is suggesting.

```
 'Security' => [
        'salt' => env('SECURITY_SALT', <Add your 256 bits (32 bytes) key here>),
    ],
```

Comment: actually i used `$this->Cookie->configKey('contactData', 'encryption', false);` in before filter and it start to work. is this correct approach to do it ?

Comment: @fatpotato This disables the encyption of cookie. Now anyone can see your cookie value as a plain text. You should not do that. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html

Comment: oh ok ok thankyou let me try this thanks for the help.

Comment: @fatpotato don't forget to accept the answer if this will work.

Comment: sorry for no response due to some work. I have done it but as i am not so much in security and encryption thing can you please tell me how to produce the key ? Or i should randomly put some words there?

Comment: @fatpotato You can use any website like https://randomkeygen.com/ to get 256 bits random key. You can use the same or modify that.